# Community Shielding mechanism?

Tags: feature-request, policy, deleted-posts

With all the mess currently happening in the Stack Exchange community, it seems like it would be appropriate to give the community more of an ability to "protect" discussions from Stack Exchange Inc. so that SE can't, for example, mass-delete meta posts about these kinds of ongoing issues.

I propose a Community Shielding mechanism, in which a well-supported community vote can make a question or answer "Shielded" from removal by moderators and SE staff. Obviously it's impossible to completely prevent removal, but SE could at least make it their policy that Community Shielded posts cannot be deleted, which could help SE rebuild trust with the community.

It would be necessary to find a way to prevent gratuitous use of Shielding, maybe by raising the vote threshold. It would have to also be policy to not remove a post while a Shielding vote is in progress, and only remove such posts by deletion votes. This could be problematic if the post is legitimately offensive, but I can't think of a decent solution for that.

Comment: Please get real. They will not let us lock them out of their own platform.

Comment: I know it's unlikely. I'm trying to offer an option for SE to get trust back.

Comment: What mass-deletion of meta posts? They deleted *one* meta question (which did have many answers). Moderators (not necessarily SE staff) deleted some posts repeating some embargoed information. Comments have been deleted  (not necessarily by SE staff)  *as always* when they are abusive, rude, tangential, or too numerous.

Comment: @AlexanderMartin They would *never* do that. And I don't blame them. If they own Stack Exchange then it wouldn't make sense to lock themselves out. Especially considering they can just undo the locks in the first place.

Comment: @Raedwald I'm not accusing SE of anything. It is however something that is possible and the possibility concerns me.

Comment: The only thing to protect the community would be to have an off-site space to discuss things

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At the end of the day the buck needs to stop somewhere. Someone has to make a decision on what belongs and what doesn't.

I guess an important question is who decides what belongs and what doesn't. In some cases, there's specific classes of flags we leave to the staff. In others we preferentially handle some of them.

With respect to current events - my priority is hopefully enabling a healthy community to come out of this at the end of all this drama.

And well some stuff doesn't quite belong - and even if the community decides that it does, someone has to make that decision and *take responsibility for it*.

So practically? If SE needs to remove content for legal reasons, they need to remove it for legal reasons, and they can make that determination themselves.

As a moderator - if I feel content has potential for hurting folks or other problems I absolutely need to be able to make that decision on my own, or in conjunction with other mods or the staff.

That is quite simply the whole point of making someone a moderator. Its with great power that comes a heavy responsibility.